# Show that $6(5^k) - 6 - 5^k + 5 = (6-1)5^k -1$. Explain it to me like I'm 5 please...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm studying for a discrete math course, and I'm finding out that I'm really weak in algebra. I don't see how this step,

$6(5^k)  - 6 - 5^k + 5 = (6-1)5^k -1$

happened in a proof I'm looking at. Thanks!

Comment: There is a $-6+5=-1$ I am sure you can handle. Now do you know factorization, even though you are 5?

Comment: Yeah it seems so easy now... the book had me confused because at this step they said they factored out a 6. So I was driving myself slowly insane...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$6(5^k) - 6 - 5^k + 5 =$$ $$6(5^k) - 5^k - 6 + 5 =$$ $$6(5^k) - 1(5^k) - 6 + 5 =$$ $$(6 - 1)5^k - 6 + 5 =$$ $$(6 - 1) 5^k - 1 $$

Comment: Thanks! You're a life saver. Do you have any general tips for me when dealing with these kinda of problems? Like what should I be asking my self at step 1 or something like that. Thanks again!

Comment: In this case, you should work with the things you know first.  You know that $-6 + 5 = -1$ so you should forget about that and ask why does $6(5^k) - 5^k = (6 - 1)5^k$.  After you ask this, you might notice it looks a lot like factorisation now that you have forgotten about the irrelevant details like the $-6 + 5$.